# Appropriate design for two experimental conditions and incomplete blocking

Tags: experiment-design, blocking, two-way

I'm planning to perform an experiment in which I will be assessing the role of two experimental variables (A: 6 levels, B: 4 levels) on a defined outcome which, however, might be affected by external factors which I will be able to control in defined blocks.
Given some experimental limitations I will not be able to assess al A x B combinations within a block, but will have to resort to an incomplete block design with only around 4-6 combinations.
Looking at a few guides online (e.g., [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~meier/teaching/anova/incomplete-block-designs.html](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Emeier/teaching/anova/incomplete-block-designs.html)) I see that they mainly deal with a single experimental variable which is not the case (and even if I consider the combinations I'll have 28 levels) and so I do not know what would be the best way to deal with this (both regarding to planning and data analysis).
How would be the more sound way to face this?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: A linear model might save you, although it might not answer the same question as an ANOVA.

Comment: What do you mean? Using `lmer` for example?

Comment: Yes, if you treat the blocks as random effects.

Comment: Ok, but would I need to plan the experiments within a block, right? (P.s. thanks for the help)

Comment: Well, yes, but you are already doing this `...which I will be able to control in defined blocks`. The design is the same, it's just the tool that changes.

Comment: Yes. I guess my doubt was about how to distribute the A x B combinations within blocks.

Comment: So in each block you will have 4-6 of the total 24 combinations? But you will have all combinations in at least one block? How many blocks will you have?

Comment: Yes, I will have only that number. I have not defined a number of blocks (it needs to be reasonable, but I can have more flexibility on that), but I will not be able to accommodate all combinations within a block. This is the reason I was looking at incomplete block design

Comment: I understand, but if you have 4-6 combinations per block then you need at least 24/4=5 blocks, preferably more. The way you assign combinations to blocks then is probably best done randomly, stratified.

Comment: Ok, yes it makes sense. This way would not remove the block effect, but at least make sure that it does not disproportionally affect one or the other experimental variable.